# Pushing CEFSharp packages to local nuget gives "406 (Not Acceptable)" error

Tags: nuget, cefsharp

I've implemented CEFSharp and need to push the required nuget packages to a local nuget server.

Other packages work fine (both created locally, or from third parties), but all of the CEFSharp packages error with `406 (Not Acceptable)`

```
C:\nuget\cef>nuget push CefSharp.Wpf.96.0.180.nupkg
Pushing CefSharp.Wpf.96.0.180.nupkg to 'http://nugetServer/Nuget/nuget/'...
  PUT http://nugetServerNuget/nuget/
  NotAcceptable http://nugetServerNuget/nuget/ 90ms
Response status code does not indicate success: 406 (Not Acceptable).
```

This happens for each of the nuget packages I try.

We're using v96.0.18, but I've tried the latest version for testing purposes.

| Package | Version | Result? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [cef.redist.x64](https://www.nuget.org/packages/cef.redist.x64/96.0.18) | 96.0.18 | Fail |
| cef.redist.x64 | 97.1.1 | Success |
| [cef.redist.x86](https://www.nuget.org/packages/cef.redist.x86/96.0.18) | 96.0.18 | Fail |
| cef.redist.x86 | 97.1.1 | Success |
| [CefSharp.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.Common/96.0.180) | 96.0.18 | Fail |
| CefSharp.Common | 97.1.11 | Fail |
| [CefSharp.Wpf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.Wpf/96.0.180) | 96.0.18 | Fail |
| CefSharp.Wpf | 97.1.11 | Fail |

No messages appear in any logs in IIS. Restarting IIS and rebooting servers hasn't worked.

We're using the latest [NuGet.Server.3.4.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Server/3.4.1) and [Nuget CLI v6.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/downloads).

Comment: The packages have a couple of warnings which are the likely cause, you'll need to find a way to ignore the warnings. I don't remember which ones exactly https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings

Comment: A quick search on the Nuget.Server GitHub repository yields https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/5084 which has a number of potential causes and some debugging tips.

Comment: https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/5084#issuecomment-475770991 The deprecated license url is one possible cause https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/NuGet/CefSharp.Common.nuspec#L9

Comment: Also https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/5084#issuecomment-486541884

Comment: @amaitland The last comment fixed it - setting `<add key="ignoreSymbolsPackages" value="false"/>` allowed the `.Common` and `.Wpf` packages with their `src/` folders. Still not sure why the `.redist` packages failed. If you'd like to post it as an answer I'll mark it

Comment: Not sure why the redist packages failed, 406 seems to be a returned for just about any error which isn't particularly helpful. Adding a trace listner is probably worth a go https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/5084#issuecomment-363460203

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CefSharp packages include the source code within the src folder.

> i received 406 because my nuget package had a src dir.
> the nuget server handles packages with src dirs as symbol packages, so in the web.config you have to set "ignoreSymbolsPackages" to false.

According to https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/5084#issuecomment-486541884 the packages will be treated as symbol packages and setting ignoreSymbolsPackages to false is required.

```
<add key="ignoreSymbolsPackages" value="false"/>
```